# Problem in alphanumeric regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

i want to validate user input for alphanumeric characters and for that im using

```
             var regex =  /^[a-zA-Z_0-9]$/;
             var asdfsfd = $('#vcr_LinkName').val();
             if (regex.test(asdfsfd)) {
                 alert("true");
             } else {
                 alert("false");                    
             }
```

but it always go into false condition what im doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression would only match one single character.

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z_0-9]+$
```

Or

```
^\w+$
```

regards

Comment: If i want to allow space as well what should i do?

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution, because this one allows tabs and linebreaks, too. But:  ^(\w|\s)+$